# Problem with using Cmake in sub directories after once using cmake on the entire project

Tags: c, windows, cmake

I have a head folder called Tutorial and sub folder called MathFunctions each having one code each
I wrote CMakeLists.txt for both the folders and used cmake in cmd promptand it is working fine.

CMakeLists.txt in head folder has the following:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED ( VERSION 2.6)

PROJECT (Tutorial)

SET (Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
SET (Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR 0)

CONFIGURE_FILE (
"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/TutorialConfig.h.in"
"${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/TutorialConfig.h "
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

OPTION (USE_MYMATH "Use tutorial provided math implementation" ON)

if (USE_MYMATH)
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/MathFunctions")

  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY (MathFunctions)
  SET (EXTRA_LIBS ${EXTRA_LIBS} MathFunctions)
endif (USE_MYMATH)

ADD_EXECUTABLE (Tutorial tutorial.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (Tutorial ${EXTRA_LIBS})
```

CMakeLists.txt in sub folder has the following:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED ( VERSION 2.6)
add_library (MathFunctions mysqrt.c )
```

and in command prompt :

```
C:\home\Tutorial\BUILD>cmake ..

-- Building for: Visual Studio 9 2008

-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 9 2008

-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 9 2008 --

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done

-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 9 2008

-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 9 2008

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

-- Configuring done

-- Generating done

-- Build files have been written to: C:/home/Tutorial/BUILD
```

Later I made some modifications in MathFunctions.c .I made no changes in Tutorial.c. So i want to re generate make files only for MathFunctions folder. But I am not able to do it. I am getting the following error

```
C:\home\Tutorial\BUILD>cmake ../MathFunctions
```

CMake Error: The source "C:/home/Tutorial/MathFunctions/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "C:/home/Tutorial/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.

I cannot figure out why this error is coming.
Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have made modifications to a source file which is already in the project, there is no need to relaunch CMake. Just recompile.

Comment: If you do run CMake again, run it as "cmake ." or with the same exact command line that you ran it with the first time. CMake caches the original value of the main top level source directory and the main top level build directory when it runs. Running "cmake ." says use the source and build directories found in the CMakeCache.txt file in the current directory. Running CMake as you originally ran it also uses the cached info. Running it with a different source directory as its main argument is an error, and will yield the error message that you got...

Answer (score 4):

OK, I know this is ancient but...had a similar problem, same error message.

There is a command under File on the GUI that cleans out the cache.  This did not work the first time but eventually it did.  I thrashed around a bit, adding cmake to the user path, reboot, don't know if any of that helped.

I got into trouble initially by trying to run cmake on a CMakeLists.txt that was NOT the root.  This error popped up when I tried again with the proper source directory.  V3.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

> .externalNativeBuild

folder from your project and sync it again. By doing this you will remove build cache.